# how to fetch a dynamic link of rss feed?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, dom, rss

I try to fetch a dynamic link of rss feed from skydrive using xmlhttp:

```
...
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
//this is the feed:
var url = "https://skydrive.live.com/feed.aspx?cid=1F8A5680599AFFF9&resid=1F8A5680599AFFF9%21120";

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
...
```

but it doesn't work - what did I do wrong? and how should I fix it?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use F12 tool available in browsers to see what's going on in network layer? I just tried your code with IE9 and it just worked.

Comment: it's definitely not working...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided a callback function for the success of your ajax call. Provide one.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
   alert(xmlhttp.responseText)
  }
```

You can also hook into the error event of `XMLHttpRequest` object to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I don't think your answer is 100% correct. The original code sets async to false therefore a callback is not necessary.

Comment: how do I use this function? what is it for?